# How can I edit text content using strictly only CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm editing a WordPress site at present. I've been researching this a bit but I can't work out why this isn't working.

The problem is I'm confined to the bounds of CSS editing only. I cannot touch the HTML. Thus I am hoping to edit content via CSS. (I realize this is abnormal).

So far I can across this suggested solution. It did however, not work for me.

Does anyone know a cool trick to edit content via CSS and not HTML, PHP, JavaScript etc...

Suggested code below not working

```css
.comment-reply-title {
display:none !important;
}

.comment-reply-title::after {
content: "New text";
text-indent: 0;
display: block;
line-height: initial;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work due the `display: none !important` rule. All pseudo elements like `::after` still hidden with that. you need to edit the text only with CSS? You don't achieve that thing with a correct and expected behaviour

Comment: Are you being explicitly told not to use javascript or you don't know how to apply javascript in wordpress? As Marcos Perez Gude mentioned remove the display:none !important; and try and avoid !important as much as you can.

Comment: ...editing a WP site but cannot change HTML? **Say What!?*

Comment: Gothical you may need to re-read the title of the question. Thanks Marcos for also the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `visibility:hidden` in `div` then apply `overflow:visible` to `::after`

`font-size:0` is to hide/collapse the extra space left by `div`

```css
.comment-reply-title {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0
}
.comment-reply-title::after {
  content: "New text";
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: 16px
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-reply-title">Old Text</div>
```